# DataContext UserControl vs Parent Child Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have an UserControl, that use Another UserControl as one of control, Parent UC has 2-3 buton and textbox as other controls. Now I set TreeView in Child usercontrol that use DataContext through my coding. It works fine, however when I add a DataContext on Parent userControl, now child user control is giving error that TreeViewItem's DataContext is of "Parent Type" and hence cannot resolve to child DataContext Type.

How can we solve this issue. I believe that when I explicitly set DataContext on child it should not get override by parent's data context.

I am new to MVVM and hence having little problem grabbing concepts. so please use easy language if possible at all :).

Edit: I just found this [WPF datacontext parent / child usercontrols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228230/wpf-datacontext-parent-child-usercontrols) However, this won't work for me as my DataContext for TreeView is not really a ViewModel, but a custom class I use as I write it. I don't want to rewrite complete ViewModel at this stage of development as my control is very much isolated from rest of project.

Edit 2:

Source for Parent Control

```
public partial class ucProjectScreen : UserControl, ITabbedWindow
{
  ProjectScreenViewModel p = new ProjectScreenViewModel();

  public long ProjectID { get; set; }
  public ucProjectScreen()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.TabName = "NoProject";
    this.TabTitle = "Project #";
    this.IsAllowRefresh = false;
    this.DataContext = p;
  }

  ...
}
```

DataContext for Child is bit tricky to share as in my usercontrol Code behind, I use Treeview Expand feature and then fetching Json string from server and making an List of out of it and pass through Itemsource property.

```
var Data = VSCommon.FetchFromWeb(URL);
List<InfoStructure> s = new List<InfoStructure>();
s = JSON.Deserialise<List<InfoStructure>>(Data);

if (s.Count > 0)
{
  List<TVDataStructure> ds = new List<TVDataStructure>();

  foreach (InfoStructure d in s)
  {
    TVDataStructure t1 = new TVDataStructure()
    {
      Header = d.Name,
      Tag = d,
      DoEvent = ((d.Type == "Directory" || d.Type == "Partition") ? true : false)
    };

    if (d.Type == "Directory" || d.Type == "Partition")
      t1.IconImage = IconReader.ToImageSource(IconReader.GetFolderIcon(IconReader.IconSize.Small, IconReader.FolderType.Closed));
    else
      t1.IconImage = IconReader.ToImageSource(IconReader.GetFileIcon(d.Name, IconReader.IconSize.Small, false));

    ds.Add(t1);
  }

  if (tds != null)
    tds.Children = ds;

  t.ItemsSource = ds;
}
```

Not sure if this helps.
Thanks

Comment: could you please post some code (not all your code!) 
just the part showing how you set the parent's DataContext and the Child's DataContext. XAML + CS

Comment: By default, the `DataContext` (data layer) behind WPF controls is inherited from the parent, and it sounds like the `DataContext` from the parent control is getting inherited by the child control. You can probably use a `RelativeSource` binding for your child control to find the correct `DataContext`, but I'm not positive without seeing your code and data layer structure. If you're new to WPF's `DataContext`, you may be interested in reading a blog post of mine: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: Make then edits of code, thanks for link let me read that :).

Comment: Thanks Rachel, your small blog post give quite a insight on topic. I realize that I am doing a bit wrong, actually I was trying to convert TreeViewItem DataContext to my DataStructure object, [my source Itesmsource when assigning] it was working fine, when we don't have parent DataContext, but now I change from Explicity casting [which was giving error] to "as <datatype>" method and it solve the problem [ironically, my code is working fine ] after this small change.